# Obter caminho do projeto

Tags: jsf

Eu tenho um projeto `JSF` e gostaria de retornar o path do projeto em uma `String`. Este path tem que pegar a pasta `webapp` como sendo a root. Como eu faço ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obter o caminho do projeto, use:

```
ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext(); 
String diretorio = ec.getRealPath("/");
```

Essa string "diretorio" vai te deixar na raiz do seu projeto.
Com isso, basta você manipular a string para ir ao diretório desejado.

Um `replace`, por exemplo, faria exatamente o desejado.